# Where is documentation to configure apache on osx 10.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, apache

I am accustomed to Apache on Ubuntu and I am trying to configure Apache with Phusion Passenger and rails etc on OSX.

There seem to be configuration files all over the place and I can't find any consistent documentation.

For example there appear to be conf file in the following locations

```
/etc/apache
/private/etc/apache2
/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2
```

Here is the output from grepping httpd

```
sh-3.2# ps -ef |grep httpd
    0  6517     1   0  6:08pm ??         0:00.22 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf -D WEBSERVICE_ON
   70  6521  6517   0  6:08pm ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf -D WEBSERVICE_ON
```

Here is the output from httpd -V

```
sh-3.2# httpd -V

Server version: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul  7 2013 18:05:17
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:31
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
Compiled using: APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/private/var/run/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

Alot of articles have instructions using the gui which I do not have access to as I am logging in to a headless server (Mac-Mini running 10.8) with ssh.

I just need to know which configuration files to use and how to do the equivalent of a2enmod and a2ensite etc that I am accustomed to on Ubuntu

Edit..

One more useful command that I stumbled on is 
sudo launchctl list org.apache.httpd.
Which gives the following output indicating that /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf is the primary config file.

```
{
    "Label" = "org.apache.httpd";
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
    "OnDemand" = false;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "PID" = 6517;
    "TimeOut" = 30;
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/usr/sbin/httpd";
        "-D";
        "FOREGROUND";
        "-f";
        "/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf";
        "-D";
        "WEBSERVICE_ON";
    );
};
```

Comment: After some research I have found that. /etc is a symbolic link to /private/etc which I had not realised before so the first two configuration files that I located are the same.

Comment: There is a ReadMe file in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2 which states "httpd_server_app.conf. 
This is the primary configuration file read by Apache. Note that it differs from the httpd.conf distributed with Apache. It is specific to Server's Apache configuration, and takes the place of the desktop Apache configuration in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf."

Comment: It seems to me that there must be a difference between OSX Desktop and Server and the docs refer to Server.app which I have established does exist in /Applications and I assume it must provide a gui for configuring Apache but as I have no GUI I cant verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that /etc and /private/etc are symbolically linked so are effectively the same place.

The location /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2 is for apache configuration if you are using the server.app which will allow you to configure apache from a gui panel. The configuration is probably not designed to be very human readable and not very suitable if you are predominantly managing the server via ssh.

In Lion you can disable the server (article [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4827))

In Mountain Lion the article does not work and I had to delete the server.app (in my case by logging in with VNC and dragging it to the trash. Its not clear whether doing an 'rm' in terminal has exactly the same effect...)

After removing server.app and restarting apache the 'normal' configuration files in /etc/apach2/httpd.conf and so forth work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the configuration is in this file (based on your output) :

```
 /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

In my case, I don't need to use a2enmod and a2ensite.This is what I've done for my site:

run `./bin/passenger-install-apache2-module` after install passenger gem.
When finish, it'll give something like this to put in your `httpd.conf` file :

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/shared/anhtd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/passenger-4.0.26/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/shared/anhtd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/passenger-4.0.26
PassengerDefaultRuby /home/shared/anhtd/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p484/ruby
```

After that when restart httpd, you can use passenger for your site, for setting up virtual host, take a look at this : http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3